# iOS Sections in UICollectionView from plist - incompatible pointer types assigning to NSString from UILabel

Tags: ios, warnings, uicollectionview

I try to make a UICollectionView with sections from .plist.
Everything functions like it has to.

But I got a warning :

Incompatible pointer types assigning to `NSString`from `UILabel`_strong.

Has somebody an idea why?

I would appreciate any help...

The problem is here:

```
UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

// here is the warning on nameLabel1...
nameLabel.text = nameLabel1;

NSLog(@"%@", nameLabel1);
```

My code:

```
#import "MainClickViewController.h"

#define animalsSection 0
#define flowersSection 1
#define buildingsSection 2
#define numberOfSections 3

@interface MainClickViewController (){
NSArray *sections;

}
 @end


@implementation MainClickViewController
@synthesize animalArray,buildingArray,flowerArray;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Load Dictionary with wood name cross refference values for image name
NSString *plistCatPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stickerei" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *creatureDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistCatPath];

self.animalArray = creatureDictionary[@"Animals"];
self.flowerArray   = creatureDictionary[@"Flowers"];
self.buildingArray   = creatureDictionary[@"Buildings"];


}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return numberOfSections;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:( NSInteger)section{


switch (section)
{
    case animalsSection:
        //return [self.bugs count];
        return [self.animalArray count];
    case flowersSection:
        //return [self.animals count];
        return [self.flowerArray count];
    case buildingsSection:
        //return [self.animals count];
        return [self.buildingArray count];
    default:
        return 0;
}


}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *imageView1  = nil;
UILabel *nameLabel1 = nil;

switch (indexPath.section)
{

    case animalsSection:

        nameLabel1 = [animalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"StickName"];
        imageView1 = [UIImage imageNamed:[animalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"StickImage"]];
        break;
    case flowersSection:
        nameLabel1 = [flowerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"StickName"];
        imageView1 = [UIImage imageNamed:[flowerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"StickImage"]];
        break;
    case buildingsSection:
        nameLabel1 = [buildingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"StickName"];
        imageView1 = [UIImage imageNamed:[buildingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"StickImage"]];
        break;

}

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
imageView.image = imageView1;

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

// here is the warning on nameLabel1...
nameLabel.text = nameLabel1;


NSLog(@"%@", nameLabel1);

cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];

return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a UILabel instance (nameLabel1) to another label text which is NSString. Try to change the declaration of nameLabel1 to NSString type.

```
NSString *nameLabel1 = nil;
```

And also you might want to change the variable name to match the type so that you won't get confused easily. For example:

```
UIImage *firstImage  = nil;
NSString *firstNameString = nil;
```